# How to translate message: Welcome, Name_User!

Tags: magento2, localisation

Magento Version: 2.0.7,
Parents Theme: Luma.

I'm trying to translate the welcome message when a client has been identified at the store: **Welcome, Name of the Client!**

I found strings for translation here:

```
"Welcome,% 1!", "Welcome,% 1!" Module, Magento_Persistent
"Welcome,% 1!", "Welcome,% 1!" Module, Magento_Theme.
```

The dictionary file is located at `app/i18n/mytema/es_es`

But translation is not displayed and continues to display the message in English.
I've also tried with the CSV file that is within the custom theme that I created, ie: `app/design/frontend/My_Tema/my_theme/i18n`. In this file I paste the chain and I have translated .... but nothing.

With layout files Magento_costumer not only translate but also alter the functionality when I create the default.xml file.
Does anyone know anything about it?

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is a bug: translation for strings rendered by javascript does not consider translation from theme file.

Here is pull request that fixes this issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/4814

As a workaround you can add your translation to translation file of a module.